# merging custom hooks for handling scroll

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to merge these two hooks to get the direction and the percentage of the scroll.

**useScrollPercentage.js**

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useScrollPercentage() {
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollPercentage, setScrollPercentage] = useState(NaN);

  const reportScroll = e => {
    setScrollPercentage(getScrollPercentage(e.target));
  };


  useEffect(
    () => {
      const node = scrollRef.current;
      if (node !== null) {
        node.addEventListener("scroll", reportScroll, { passive: true });
        if (Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage)) {
          setScrollPercentage(getScrollPercentage(node));
        }
      }
      return () => {
        if (node !== null) {
          node.removeEventListener("scroll", reportScroll);
        }
      };
    },
    [scrollPercentage]
  );

  return [scrollRef, Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage) ? 0 : scrollPercentage];
}

function getScrollPercentage(element) {
  if (element === null) {
    return NaN;
  }
  const height = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
  return Math.round((element.scrollTop / height) * 100);
}
```

**useScrollDirection.js**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function useScrollDirection({
  ref,
  threshold,
  debounce,
  scrollHeightThreshold,
}) {
  threshold = threshold || 10;
  debounce = debounce || 10;
  scrollHeightThreshold = scrollHeightThreshold || 0;
  const [scrollDir, setScrollDir] = useState(null);
  const debouncedSetScrollDir = _.debounce(setScrollDir, debounce);

  useEffect(() => {
    let lastScrollY = ref?.current?.scrollTop;
    let lastScrollDir;
    let ticking = false;
    const hasScrollHeightThreshold =
      ref?.current?.scrollHeight - ref?.current?.clientHeight >
      scrollHeightThreshold;

    const updateScrollDir = () => {
      const scrollY = ref?.current?.scrollTop;
      if (
        Math.abs(scrollY - lastScrollY) < threshold ||
        !hasScrollHeightThreshold
      ) {
        ticking = false;
        return;
      }
      const newScroll = scrollY > lastScrollY ? 'Down' : 'Up';
      if (newScroll !== lastScrollDir) {
        debouncedSetScrollDir(newScroll);
      }
      lastScrollY = scrollY > 0 ? scrollY : 0;
      lastScrollDir = newScroll;
      ticking = false;
    };

    const onScroll = () => {
      if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScrollDir);
        ticking = true;
      }
    };

    ref?.current?.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);

  return scrollDir;
}
```

Currently I am using it like this

**App.js**

```
 const [scrollRef, scrollPercentage] = useScrollPercentage();
  const scrollDirection = useScrollDirection({ref: scrollRef});

  const handleScroll = () => {
   console.log(scrollPercentage, scrollDirection);
  }

  return (
    <Modal ref={scrollRef} onScroll={handleScroll}>
    // Scrollable Content      
   </Modal>
  )
```

The problem is that since I don't want to trigger useScrollDirection for every scroll percentage unless the scroll direction changed only it should trigger. Also is it possible to merge these hooks?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `I don't want to trigger useScrollDirection for every scroll percentage` the component will re-render because of scrollPercentage changing anyway no ? What if you put `useScrollPercentage` inside `useScrollDirection`, that should be the same and make you call a single hook no ?

Comment: Right thought , but not sure how to place that into useScrollDirection and get percentage and direction with single hook